# Start Bounty fails

Tags: bug, bounty

I am trying to start a bounty [on this question of mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/celebration-how-to-golf-a-marriage-with-a-prefix-free-code)

I get to the start bounty window:

---

### [image]

But nothing happens when I press the `"Start Bounty"` button.

Is there something wrong with the question? My browser? Should I start a bounty on [this question](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/start-bounty-fails) to get an answer?

**Edit**

Changed to [bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) since [it was confirmed by another user](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5588759#5588759).

**Edit**

Removed [bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) since [it worked for another user](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/start-bounty-fails#comment1886_595).

Comment: Hmm, someone reported [something similar on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141671/why-cant-i-start-a-bounty) yesterday, but in their case at least the problem was only temporary.

Comment: @TimStone Well, [seems I'm not the only one](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5588759#5588759), and it is still there :(

Comment: If I were to test this and it works for me, I'd have to pay a bounty, right?

Comment: @R.M And how would I do that? I have started the bounty and it works for me.

Comment: @R.M ;-) I never needed this before, so didn't know I could do this... You must have done this often I guess ;-p

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries That was the idea behind `Should I start a bounty on this question to get an answer?`

Comment: Tagged [tag:bug] again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by using IE instead of FF. Perhaps an addon is interfering with JS.